# How can I export a counter that resets every restart to bosun and trust the absolute number?

Tags: statistics, counter, metrics, opentsdb, bosun

I am sending a counter that can reset at any point. I sent the counter every 5 seconds but I don't reset it every 5 seconds, only when the app restarts, which is regularly.

I need to be able to tell how many impressions did my server got last week, but I can't do a sum() because bosun will just add 10, 12, 15, 25, 0, 1, 5, 10....
So, it does take in account that for rate calculation, but not for summing or any other thing.

Would bosun handle it better if I restarted the counter every time I send it? seems easier, but the docs on bosun/opentsdb state that this is not necessary and not to do it.

Comment: Support for this type of aggregator is not a good enough reason to swap the underlying datastore, but Axibase Time Series Database runs on HBase, supports Bosun collection protocol and provides 'counter' aggregator: https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/54e57188. Disclosure: I work for Axibase.

Answer (score 3):

OpenTSDB should automatically handle sum/average aggregation of counters when you use them as a rate instead of a raw gauge. It takes two sample points and calculates the difference, giving you total "impressions" between the two sample points. Note it may also change the value to "per second" since that is the standard for OpenTSDB.

Whenever the second value is lower than the first, OpenTSDB will disregard that datapoint and wait for the next data point to be sent before it will continue the rate calculations. For this reason you should try and minimize counter resets or overflows if possible (anything less than an hour may cause noticeable artifacts).

We actually use a special [/api/count route on tsdbrelay](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/commit/240b4079c826760acc855dfe739bef0691cedd70) to aggregate incremental counts from multiple hosts into a more "stable" counter for some metrics on our web tier, since it gets built frequently and the counter resets were impacting our alerts and monitoring dashboard. If this is of interest to you stop by the [Bosun Slack room](https://bosun.org/slackInvite)  for more details.

I highly advise you watch the [Bosun fundamentals playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWetmRzVkFTdnjRmE-a-JRx2m8qgB6iu9) which describe the use of Gauge vs Counter in much more detail.